# Не могу добиться, чтобы пользователь через форму мог загружать изображения на сайт

Tags: django, изображения

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста, новичку. Никак не могу добиться, чтобы фото, отправленное через форму появилось на сайте. В форме есть фото и текст, текст отображается на сайте. Фото нет. Вообще ни намека. Через админку видно как фото прикреплено к форме и всё. Но на сайте вообще даже тег scr не отображается. Сайт полностью игнорирует вывод изображения.

Для простоты описания проблемы построил специальные упрощенные модель, функцию и шаблон без лишней лабуды, чтобы была видна только суть.

модел:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

формс:

```
class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comment', 'image']
```

вьюшка:

```
def testimage(request):
    comments=Comments.objects.all()
    context={'comments': comments}
    return render(request, 'countries/testimage.html', context)

def testimage_add(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form=CommentsForm()
    else:
        form=CommentsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('countries:testimage'))
    context={'form': form}
    return render(request, 'countries/testimage_add.html', context)
```

testimage.html

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {% if comment.image %}
    <li> <img scr="{{comment.image}}"></li>
  {% endif %}
{% empty %}
  <li>No comments </li>
{% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'countries:testimage_add' %}"> Press here to add comment</a>
```

testimage_add.html

```
<form action="{% url 'countries:testimage_add' %}" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button name="submit">TRY</button>
</form>
```

urls.py всего проекта в целом:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('countries.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'countries/static/countries')
```

Что не так?? Почему фото не отображаются на сайте?? MEDIA_ROOT и MEDIA_URL уже по всякому пробовал менять, ничего не получается. Форма принимает фотографию, сохраняет ее в папке, я вижу как папка растет, фотки туда попадают из формы. Но сам сайт не отображает!!

Comment: Почему у вас `input type="file"` внутри тега `<form>`? И что по-вашему содержится в `request.FILES`?

Comment: Изменил вопрос, упросил код максимально, посмотрите теперь. Ну что сейчас то не так?? Ну все как по учебнику, а толку нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает, когда вы пытаетесь неправильно перезаписать картинку. В вашем случае легче воспользоваться не `ModelForm`, а просто [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).

Создадим форму для валидации полей `description` и [`image`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield):

```
class DescriptionsForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 100}))
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

Теперь во вью мы можем использовать нашу форму:

```
def new_description(request, countries_id, cities_id):
    country = Countries.objects.get(id=countries_id)
    city = Cities.objects.get(id=cities_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = DescriptionsForm()
    else:
        form = DescriptionsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            # Добавим объект Descriptions
            Descriptions.objects.create(
                city=city,
                description=description,
                owner=request.user,
                image=image
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('countries:descr', args=[country.id, city_name.id]))
    context = {'country': country, 'city': city, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'countries/new_description.html', context)
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо, что откликнулись, но не помогает( А как же привязать этот новый комментарий пользователя с темой, в которой он создан? То есть по идее пользователь должен оставлять отзыв о городе, в котором он побывал, соответственно каждый пост должен быть связан с городом. Если не прописать new_description.city=city_name, то как пост сохранится именно в ветке соответствующего города? В общем вылазиет ошибка в таком случае( Беда какая то...

Comment: подправил ответ, попробуйте так, должно работать.

Comment: Ошибка исчезла! Но вот на сайте изображения так и не хотят появляться. Если, например, зайти в админку, и найти пост, образованный отправленной формой, то видно текст (который отображается на сайте) и фото прикреплено (которое на сайте не отражается), так вот если кликнуть по фото, то оно благополучно открывается в браузере, url такой localhost:8000/media/images/photo3_1EZRQxg.jpg
И даже если на самом сайте, нажать кнопку "редактировать пост", то открывается этот пост, образованный формой, виден текст, и фото снизу прикреплено тоже, оно тоже в браузере открывается теперь, url такой же

Comment: НО на самом сайте, в посте не хочет появляться. Наверное что то в настройках не то?(

Вот такие настройки в settings:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: в настройках всё должно быть нормально, я не совсем понимаю в каком именно шаблоне от какой вью у вас не отображается изображение, приведите пример кода в основном вопросе

Comment: Сергей, я изменил основной вопрос, убрал все лишнее, только голый код для формы, загрузки фото и отображения. Без лишней лабуды. Все как по учебнику. Ну почему, почему, почему сайт не показывает фото из формы ???

Comment: у вас не отображается изображение в шаблоне testimage.html или в шаблоне testimage_add.html? если в testimage_add.html, то там и не будет отобажаться, у вас это вью создания объекта, а не изменения. для изменения используйте немного другую логику

Comment: Именно в  testimage.html не отображается.

Comment: Тег  <img scr="{{comment.image}}">   НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

Comment: У меня уже руки опускаются. НИКТО не может ответить. В интернете информации вообще тупо нет, и даже официальная документация не дает ответа. Это какой то беспросветный тупик.

Comment: Всё, заработало! Спасибо!